# How does one call the down method for a Doctrine migration in Symfony 1.2?

Tags: php, symfony1, migration, doctrine

I am using Symfony 1.2 with the sfDoctrinePlugin.

I couldn't find any command to call the `down` method on a migration, neither the documentation suggests any related arguments to the existing `doctrine migrate` command.
What would be a way to rollback the migration I just ran successfully? Creating a new migration to undo is an option, but that is almost blasphemous and plainly stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are at Migration Version N, then

```
./symfony doctrine:migrate N-1
```

will call the down method on the N<sup>th</sup> migration.

Comment: php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate DoctrineMigrations\Version20200828082530

Answer (score 5):

You could also do

```
./symfony doctrine:migrate --down
```

as by the docu:

```
symfony doctrine:migrate [--application[="..."]] [--env="..."] [--up] [--down] [--dry-run] [version]
```

Comment: Hmm.. I am quite certain that it was missing from the documentation when I looked at it. Of course, I could have been wrong.

Comment: You could easily be right because the post is rather old and there have been changes to the way doctrine commands work since then. I was googling around having the same question in mind so thanks for posting it!

Comment: FYI this is only for Symfony 1 ! in Symfony2 it says "The "--down" option does not exist.  "

Comment: Sliq, I don't understand the downvote. The original question was about Symfony 1.2. Please mind the context.

Answer (score 1):

Just give the migration number you would like to migrate to and Doctrine will determine whether to call `up` or `down`. See the [API docs for migrate in 1.2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Migration/1_2#method_migrate):

> (integer) migrate($to = null, $dryRun
>   = false)
>
> Perform a migration process by
>   specifying the migration
>   number/version to migrate to. It will
>   automatically know whether you are
>   migrating up or down based on the
>   current version of the database.
>
> returns Version number migrated to
>
> throws Doctrine_Exception

Comment: Right. Had to read the code to figure that out. Didn't read the docs you mentioned.

Comment: I was more inclined to find the command line way to run that method.